# Issues with jQuery .before

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm building a very simple carousel with 4 divs. It uses 2 jQuery functions to set a div to either first or last position. There is only alpha transitions as I don't need movement.

For some reason, though I can access my divs with .eg(n) etc, but the first, last and other various numbers aren't working in this function.

Code:

```
$('#prev').click(function() {

    $('.container .divname').animate({opacity: 0}, 1000,function(){ 

     $('.container .divname:first').before($('.container .divname:last')); 

     $('.container .divname').animate({opacity: 1}, 1000); 

    });

    return false;

});
```

So that function isn't working.

```
$('#prev').click(function() {

        $('.container .divname').animate({opacity: 0}, 1000,function(){ 

         $('.container .divname:eq(0)').before($('.container .divname:eq(3)')); 

         $('.container .divname').animate({opacity: 1}, 1000); 

        });

        return false;

    });
```

This also doesn't work, but if I change the **eq(3)** to **eq(2)** it does, but obviously misses one of my divs. I can still access the eq(3) because I tested it, and made it's background red.

```
$('.container .divname:eq(3)').css({'background-color' : '#ff0000'});
```

This works...

Can anyone please tell me why this maybe happening?

Html example is as below

```
<html>
     <div class="container">
          <div class="divname">
               <p>some content</p>
          </div>
          <div class="divname">
               <p>some content</p>
          </div>
          <div class="divname">
               <p>some content</p>
          </div>
          <div class="divname">
               <p>some content</p>
          </div>
     </div>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**

I have changed all the id to class now for the w3c kids in the audience. Issue still resides.

http://jsfiddle.net/3P8t5/1/

Comment: Ids should really be unique.

Comment: Yeah I realize my coding is a bit rough, but this won't solve the issue will it?

Comment: As ids are unique so it must not assign to second element in the page due to this it makes a invalid html as w3c recommends.

Comment: Ok, i'll change the id to a class edit if the issue still occurs. Still makes no sense how I can access them individually but not in the function itself. Still, I'll make the changes so we can get that issue out the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of your problem is that you have put your .before() function to shift the divs in a callback function attached to your four divs - thus it is called four times meaning everything is shifted four times bringing you back to square one ...and becuase it's such a simple little loop, it's fast and it appears nothing has happened.

Solution - attach the animate function to just the container;

```
$('#prev').click(function() {

// Fade just the container - not each placeholder meaning the callback function is only called once, not four times
$('.container').animate({
    opacity: 0
}, 1000, function() {

    $('.container .divname:eq(0)').before($('.container .divname:eq(3)'));

    // Fade back in just the container - not each placeholder
    $('.container').animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 1000);
});
return false;
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cywjs/1/

Comment: Barry Mcgee, you are a genius! Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

other than friends suggested (Ids should really be unique) i saw misspell in your code.change `"divnaname"` to `"divname"` in the div tags.e.g: `<div id="divnaname"> ... <div>`

**Edit:**

check this demo [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3P8t5/)

is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: That's actually just a temp name for the sake of this post but thanks, i'll tweak it.

Comment: it is not important how you are naming tags but they must be same in the murkup and jquery selector.

Comment: Not exactly but close. I want previous to send 4 to the front of the queue, like 1,2,3,4, then press prev and achieve 4,1,2,3. Obviously with a next button it would go from 1,2,3,4 to 2,3,4,1.